# Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 Error

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I'm trying to install Microsoft Exchange Server 2010 onto a Windows Server 2008 r2 Standard machine. After the installation I rebooted my server and got this error. Every post I've seen online is different! Can anyone help me resolve this?

"the WinRM client cannot process the request. It cannot determine the content type of the HTTP response from the destination computer. The content type is absent or invalid. For more information, see the about_Report_Troubleshooting Help topic. It was running the command 'Discover-ExchangeServer -UseWIA $true -SuppressError $true"

Here is an image of the error as well:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

looks like its the missing key in registry issue.

try these steps:

Export and save a copy of registry before editing.

> regedit.exe -> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Exchange\ ->
>   Crete Key named "Setup", if existing, skip step -> Create new String
>   value "Services" in Setup Key -> Set value data as the path to
>   exchange directory

Once done, Save it and reboot.

Comment: When you say set the path to the exchange directory. Do you mean the program files folder, or the directory that I wish to store all the mail boxes etc..

Comment: programs files exchange server folder